# AWS lambda no trigger displayed in the AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, openapi, aws-lambda-integration

After I deployed my Open API in API gateway with lambda integration, I don't see the integration in Lambda itself. But I'm able to call the lambda from API gateway. Is this normal when integrating with Open API?

[image]

Comment: Yes that's normal. Lambda is the backend for API Gateway in this instance. API Gateway isn't considered a "trigger".

Comment: Not a trigger as Mark said

Comment: @MarkB does this break the event-driven architecture of lambda?